# Not running before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a model with `before_save :autofill_country_code` which will fill missing values. However, when I run my rspec test, it doesn't seem to run the before_save.

I pried my test open and saving did not update the attributes.

How do I work around this?

```
it "should autofill country code" do
    empty_country_code = ''
    @store = Factory.build(:store, :country_code => empty_country_code)
    expect{ @store.save }.to change{ @store.country_code }.from('').to(1)
end
```

The following is my autofill code:

```
def autofill_country_code
  unless self.country_code.present?
    country = GeoCache.geocode(self.city).country_code
    country_code = IsoCountryCodes.find(country).calling
    self.country_code = country_code.tr('+', '')
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post your `autofill` method. I'm gona bet it will all work if you do `empty_country_code = nil` instead.

Comment: I've added my autofill code. I tried adding changing it to nil but that hasn't passed the test.

Comment: You're calling `before_save :autofill` but your method is called `authofill_country_code`, is there another method which is supposed to call it?

Comment: Edited: it is supposed to call `autofill_country_code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have validation set up for `country_code`? Hooks are performed in that order:

```
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_create
around_create
after_create
after_save
```

So if model is invalid, before_save hook will not be executed. Try `before_validation :autofill_country_code` instead.

Comment: I have validation for country_code. The before_save hook is being executed. However, it is still not updating empty values despite this.